# Magento Patch for PHP Version 5.4

Tags: php, magento, patch

Anyone experience this error during applying Magento PATCH for Php 5.4 latest version

```
$ sh PATCH_SUPEE-2629_EE_1.12.0.0_v1.sh
```

I also tried this Instruction but It didn’t work for me:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/apply-revert-magento-patches?icid=BLOG_php54_knowledgebase

```
PATCH_SUPEE-2629_EE_1.12.0.0_v1.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-2629_EE_1.12.0.0_v1.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-2629_EE_1.12.0.0_v1.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-2629_EE_1.12.0.0_v1.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-2629_EE_1.12.0.0_v1.sh: 25: PATCH_SUPEE-2629_EE_1.12.0.0_v1.sh: 0: not found
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php

Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 

Apply anyway? [n] 

Skipping patch.

1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php.rej

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php

Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 

Apply anyway? [n] 

Skipping patch.

1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php.rej

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml

Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 

Apply anyway? [n] 

Skipping patch.

1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml.rej

The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 

Apply anyway? [n] 

Skipping patch.

1 out of 1 hunk ignored
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem: command not found: line 7

Comment: Same problem, the 1 current answer doesn't work in my case, but was useful in that I've now eliminated another possibility.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

The reason you are seeing that particular response is because (most likely) the patch is already applied.

I've ran a quick patch on a clean Magento install:

```
oleg@sandbox:~/www/magento_enterprise$ sudo sh PATCH_SUPEE-2619_EE_1.13.1.0_v1-2014-01-21-05-52-03.sh
PATCH_SUPEE-2619_EE_1.13.1.0_v1-2014-01-21-05-52-03.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-2619_EE_1.13.1.0_v1-2014-01-21-05-52-03.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-2619_EE_1.13.1.0_v1-2014-01-21-05-52-03.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-2619_EE_1.13.1.0_v1-2014-01-21-05-52-03.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-2619_EE_1.13.1.0_v1-2014-01-21-05-52-03.sh: 25: PATCH_SUPEE-2619_EE_1.13.1.0_v1-2014-01-21-05-52-03.sh: 0: not found
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
Patch was applied/reverted successfully.
```

Now, as you can see it patched successfully without any issues. After the successful patch I ran the same patch again and got this:

```
oleg@sandbox:~/www/magento_enterprise$ sudo sh PATCH_SUPEE-2619_EE_1.13.1.0_v1-2014-01-21-05-52-03.sh
PATCH_SUPEE-2619_EE_1.13.1.0_v1-2014-01-21-05-52-03.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-2619_EE_1.13.1.0_v1-2014-01-21-05-52-03.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-2619_EE_1.13.1.0_v1-2014-01-21-05-52-03.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-2619_EE_1.13.1.0_v1-2014-01-21-05-52-03.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-2619_EE_1.13.1.0_v1-2014-01-21-05-52-03.sh: 25: PATCH_SUPEE-2619_EE_1.13.1.0_v1-2014-01-21-05-52-03.sh: 0: not found
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php.rej
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
```

Looks very similar to what you have there.

Try running:

```
sudo sh YOUR_PATCH.sh --list
```

to see what patches have been applied to you Magento installation to confirm if your patch is already applied.

My output after applying the patch above is:

```
oleg@sandbox:~/www/magento_enterprise$ sudo sh PATCH_SUPEE-2619_EE_1.13.1.0_v1-2014-01-21-05-52-03.sh --list
PATCH_SUPEE-2619_EE_1.13.1.0_v1-2014-01-21-05-52-03.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-2619_EE_1.13.1.0_v1-2014-01-21-05-52-03.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-2619_EE_1.13.1.0_v1-2014-01-21-05-52-03.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-2619_EE_1.13.1.0_v1-2014-01-21-05-52-03.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-2619_EE_1.13.1.0_v1-2014-01-21-05-52-03.sh: 25: PATCH_SUPEE-2619_EE_1.13.1.0_v1-2014-01-21-05-52-03.sh: 0: not found
-e Applied/reverted patches list:
-e 2014-02-07 23:29:18 UTC | SUPEE-2619 | EE_1.13.1.0 | v1 | d0a215a139aa5e75d60e42efa1b2661d84fef2be | Tue Dec 10 17:41:31 2013 +0200 | v1.13.1.0..HEAD
-e 2014-02-12 10:24:33 UTC | SUPEE-2619 | EE_1.13.1.0 | v1 | d0a215a139aa5e75d60e42efa1b2661d84fef2be | Tue Dec 10 17:41:31 2013 +0200 | v1.13.1.0..HEAD | REVERTED
```

You can also revert the patch and try repatching Magento again. To revert a patch run:

```
sudo sh YOUR_PATCH.sh -R
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've got the same problem as the OP and the "Applied/reverted patches list:" returns "<empty>".